# Counting Visible Blank cells in a row

Tags: excel, vba

I have a data set with a large number of blank fields in each column. I would like to count the number of blank cells in each column after I've applied some arbitrary filters to other column(s).

I've gotten this to work in a `sub` with the following

```
 Sub whatever()
 Dim myrange As Range
 Set myrange = Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("a1:a100")
 myrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count     
 End Sub
```

But when I try to put it in a UDF like so

```
 Function CountBlankVisible(myrange As Range)
 CountBlankVisible = myrange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Count
 End Function
```

It seems to be counting every cell in the range regardless of cell type. Any ideas why this would work in a sub but not as a function? is it possible to get this count some other way?

Comment: possible duplicate of [VBA UDF gives different answer when called from Excel vs VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14141513/vba-udf-gives-different-answer-when-called-from-excel-vs-vba)

Comment: thanks @brettdj. for those who don't want to click the link the `SpecialCells` method doesn't behave properly in a UDF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Excel UDF has some limitations (when called from worksheet). You can read about them [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/170787/en-us).

Here is working example:

```
Function CountBlankVisible(myrange As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In myrange
        If c.RowHeight > 0 And IsEmpty(c.Value) Then _
            CountBlankVisible = CountBlankVisible + 1
    Next
End Function
```

Comment: I don't think my function is trying to do any of the limitations described in your link.  Also your function is returning some values, but I don't think its the number of blanks in the column. What is the significance of `rowheight=0`?

Comment: I updated my asnwer, there should be `c.RowHeight > 0` (when row is invisible, it's row height is 0)

Comment: also check this link: http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2010-customize/udf-not-working-properly-count-comments/d586fa6b-5d44-405b-9471-946ddd2250e6

Answer (score 1):

As an alternative to simoco's code:

```
Function CountBlankVisible(myrange As Range)
    Dim c As Range
    For Each c In myrange
        If Not c.EntireRow.Hidden And c.Value ="" Then
            CountBlankVisible = CountBlankVisible + 1
        End If
    Next
End Function
```